# How can I add AES for Windows form using SQL Server database

Tags: sql, encryption, aes, c#-2.0, sql-server-express

I need to know how to encrypt data in a SQL Server database. I used various code but in some program `AES` class is not there, I searched for solution, and I tried so many times to get it. Help needed. everything is working fine, but `Aes` is coming in red underlines, I don't have any class for `Aes` encryptor.

I used this code.

```
private void InsertQuery()
{
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into data(username,password,age) values (@username,@password,@age)", con);

        try
        {
            if (txtUsername.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error ! \n Please enter Username");
            }
            else if (txtPassword.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error ! \n Please enter Password");
            }
            else if (Convert.ToSingle(txtAge.Text) > 99)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error ! \n Please enter Age Correctly");
            }
            else
            {
                con.Open();

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUsername.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password",Encryptdata(txtPassword.Text.Trim()));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", txtAge.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("SUCCESS!");
                con.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error! Age is not valid!");
        }
    }

    private string Encryptdata(string clearText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);

        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }

        return clearText;
    }

    private string Decrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }

        return cipherText;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Function is used to Decrypt the password
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="password"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private string Decryptdata(string encryptpwd)
    {
        string decryptpwd = string.Empty;
        UTF8Encoding encodepwd = new UTF8Encoding();
        Decoder Decode = encodepwd.GetDecoder();
        byte[] todecode_byte = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptpwd);
        int charCount = Decode.GetCharCount(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length);
        char[] decoded_char = new char[charCount];
        Decode.GetChars(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length, decoded_char, 0);
        decryptpwd = new String(decoded_char);
        return decryptpwd;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check [This MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes(v=vs.110).aspx) AES is not there in C#2.0, but you have other alternative of AES like **Rijndael**, you can use it by adding reference to **System.Security.Cryptography**, Please have look at [This MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndael(v=vs.80).aspx) for it.

Hope it helps..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can let SQL Server handle the encryption. Check into the SQL function [EncryptByKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174361).